# HTML navigation on bottom of screen and stick to top

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

i'd like to create an effect to the navigation(exemple:http://theme.co/x/). I want the navigation to be every time i refresh the page at bottom of screen , and when it scrolls down to stick to the top. Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You probably arn't aware but this is not a code writing service. Please include some code to recreate your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Attach an event listener to the scroll event, and when the scroll position is greater than the desired position, add a class to the nav element that sets it's `position` to `fixed` and `top` to `0`.

Comment: your answer works only for a single resolution , if the screen its resized the disered position changes . So i want it to dynamically figure out when to set position fixed attribute.

Comment: No. Your logic only works for a single resolution. Instead of hardcoding one specific value as a trigger point, use a dynamic position such as the viewport height minus the outer-height of the navigation bar. That value needs to be calculated every time the scroll event is called (or only during orientationchange/resize/load events).

Answer (score 0):

theme.co website, attach an event to scroll event, and add o remove css class(http://theme.co/x/wp-content/themes/x-child-custom/framework/js/x-custom.js):

```
$window.scroll(function() {
      var $menutop = $navbarWrap.offset().top - $navbar.outerHeight();
      var $current = $this.scrollTop();
      if ($current >= $menutop) {
        $navbar.addClass('x-navbar-fixed-top');
      } else {
        $navbar.removeClass('x-navbar-fixed-top');
      }
    });
```